# Конвертировать json в лист. Сгруппировать лист по категориям

Tags: android, json

```
{
  meta: {
    limit: 0,
    offset: 0,
    total_count: 49
  },
  objects: [
    {
      category: "РџРµРІРµС†/РџРµРІРёС†Р°",
      created_at: "2016-07-04T11:27:49.050021",
      description: "hccjcj ",
      email: "xcjcu@hh.ru",
      extra_phone_number: "8582838",
      id: 64,
      name: "РіР°РіРіСЃРіСЃСЃРіСЃСЃРіСЃРіСЃРіСЃРіСЃС€РјС€РјС€Рї",
      phone_number: "688838383838388383",
      photo_url: "",
      price: 6868,
      resource_uri: "/api/post/64/",
      surname: "РѕСЃРѕРјРјРѕРјРіРї",
      updated_at: "2016-07-04T11:27:49.050069",
      video_url: null
    },
    {
      category: "РўР°РјР°РґР°",
      created_at: "2016-07-04T08:03:58.411222",
      description: "gsgvs",
      email: "sgha@ejs.com",
      extra_phone_number: "5465",
      id: 63,
      name: "ysuhhs",
      phone_number: "0123456789",
      photo_url: "",
      price: 1235,
      resource_uri: "/api/post/63/",
      surname: "gsjeg",
      updated_at: "2016-07-04T08:03:58.411287",
      video_url: null
    },
```

Этот json нужно сконвертировать в объекты класса Person. эти объекты сгруппировать по категориям.

```
Data list =  new Gson().fromJson(json,Data.class);
return list.getList().size();
```

выдает `NullPointerExeption.`

```
public class Data implements Serializable{
  private List<Person> list;

   public void setList(List<Person> list) {
      this.list = list;
   }

   public List<Person> getList() {
      return list;
   }
}
```

класс Person

```
public class  Person implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String surname;
    String category;
    String price;
    String bitmap;
    String description;
    String region;
    String created_at;
    String email;
    String phone_number;
    String video_url;
    String id;
+ setters & getters
}
```

Comment: и в чем у вас проблема именно? Или вы хотите ,чтобы кто-то написал вам готовый код?

Comment: Data list =  new Gson().fromJson(json,Data.class);
list  остается пустым. public class Data implements Serializable{
  private List<Person> list;

   public void setList(List<Person> list) {
      this.list = list;
   }

   public List<Person> getList() {
      return list;
   }
}

Comment: отрерактируйте вопрос, и вставьте туда свой код.

Comment: И вам стоит почитать урок по GSON, Т. к. вы понятия не имеете, как с ним работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson десериализует json по именам свойств, т.е. чтобы получить `objects` у вас в `Data` должно быть свойство `objects`, а не `list`. Поэтому либо

```
public class Data implements Serializable {
    List<Person> objects;
}
```

, либо (более гибкий метод) указать из какого свойства json десериализовать в ваш `list`:

```
public class Data implements Serializable{
    @SerializedName("objects") List<Person> list;
}
```